# Css - auto grid list of photos(angular 6)

Tags: css, angular, html

I want to create a grid list that dynamically works with Angular 6 `*ngFor` directive. My question/problem is that I have Array of 105 objects in firebase. Structure of object is like:

```
{src: 'some url', alt: 'title'}
```

Now I have 2 different type of photos, one horizontal, one vertical. I want to create auto filling section that will fill up empty space, I know that can be do with grid list in css3. But how to connect that with :

```
<div class="row">
<div class="imageGallery1 " *ngFor="let image of galleryList">
  <a  [href]="image.src" [title]="image.alt">
    <img [src]="image.src" [alt]="image.alt" style="max-width: 300px; max-height: 300px; object-fit: contain; padding-right: 20px;" />
  </a>

</div>
```

**styles are only for create temp thumbnails**

Is there any way to check what kind of type each photo has? (vertical, horizontal) and later auto sortu out them ? Please point me if there's any other way to do this

Comment: Are you looking for `background-size: contain;` ?

Comment: Read about grid list pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution on youtube course of grid css.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6CBKf8K_Ac

css:

```
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}
.imageGallery1 {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;

  & img {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 510px;
    height: 251px;

  }
}

.vertical {
  grid-row: span 2;
  & img {
    height: 510px;
  }

}
```

and now each vertical photo has its own class with `grid-row: span 2;`

Maybe i could help someone